# How to do with css that the text doesn't stop?

Tags: html, css, animation, perspective

I want to make a text that is constantly moving.
I've seen an example and I liked it, but I tried to modify it and it broke it.
Now the text that rotates through two different planes, but is not continuous, is hidden but the continuation of the sentence does not appear.

To give an example, it is as if a train of 6 wagons goes around a circuit, but in some sections only 3 or 4 of the wagons appear
You can see the example.
The idea is that the text does not stop rotating but in a more realistic and continuous way, now the sentence is broken

How can this be corrected so that the sentence always looks complete?

What must be done so that the text does not stop and the sentence is always continuous?

I have tried to increase the size of the planes, but it does not work, the sentence is broken anyway
Thank you

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: navajowhite;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.box .inner {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  font-size: 6em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box .inner:first-child {
  background-color: indianred;
  color: darkred;
  transform-origin: right;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-15deg);
}

.box .inner:last-child {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  color: antiquewhite;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(15deg);
}

.box .inner span {
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.box .inner:first-child span {
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
  left: -100%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  from {
    left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>texto en 3D</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inner">
      <span>welcome to my restaurant</span>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <span>welcome to my restaurant</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have modified the style file without success

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: navajowhite;
}

.box {
    display: flex;
}

.box .inner {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 6em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box .inner:first-child {
    background-color: indianred;
    color: darkred;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(-15deg);
}

.box .inner:last-child {
    background-color: lightcoral;
    color: antiquewhite;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(15deg);
}

.box .inner span {
    position: absolute;
    animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.box .inner:first-child span {
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
    left: -100%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }

    to {
        left: -100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The `.box` element has been widened to `1200px` and given a perspective value of `1000px`. The `transform-origin` property on the `.box .inner` elements has been adjusted to position the text closer to the front of the box and prevent it from disappearing behind the sides.

The animation property on the `.box .inner` span elements has been slowed down to `20` seconds, and the from and to values in the `@keyframes` rule have been changed to use `transform` instead of `left`, which allows for a smoother and more continuous motion.

With these changes, the text should rotate smoothly and continuously without any breaks in the sentence.

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      background-color: navajowhite;
    }

    .box {
      display: flex;
      width: 1200px;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }

    .box .inner {
      width: 600px;
      height: 300px;
      line-height: 300px;
      font-size: 6em;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .box .inner:first-child {
      background-color: indianred;
      color: darkred;
      transform-origin: 100% 50%;
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-30deg);
    }

    .box .inner:last-child {
      background-color: lightcoral;
      color: antiquewhite;
      transform-origin: 0% 50%;
      transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(30deg);
    }

    .box .inner span {
      position: absolute;
      animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
    }

    .box .inner:first-child span {
      animation-delay: 0s;
      left: 100%;
    }

    @keyframes marquee {
      from {
        transform: translateX(100%);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateX(-150%);
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>texto en 3D</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="inner">
          <span>welcome to my restaurant</span>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
          <span>welcome to my restaurant</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the delay in responding.
I only have two doubts regarding your example, 1 - how can I get the phrase to always be moving? I mean, when the sentence disappears on the left, it should automatically appear on the right. How can we get that? Thank you @Khabibkhanov

Comment: Hi, I am also sorry for the delay, I think it is working as u want, and then I edited it again yesterday, check it out )@unity-student

Comment: Thank you. Everything works fine. It would only be necessary that when the phrase is hidden on the left side of the "box", it automatically shows itself again on the right side of the "box" without any second, that is, that the phrase appears again on the right side of the "box" " without any delay after hiding on the right side. I don't know how we can achieve that, I'm sure you know what I mean. If you can help me ?

Comment: Ahh, I see, Okay, to achieve that, you can change `from {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}` to `from {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}`

If it works as u want, let me know )